# Graph theory problem where squares in a square are shaded such that no shaded square can be on the same 'lane' as another shaded square

Tags: graph-theory

I came across a question on the internet and haven't been able to find it again. ***Maximum number of shaded squares in a larger square (all smaller squares are of the same size) such that no two squares can be horizontal or diagonal to each other***.

Note: This isn't the actual question just what i can remember of it. I also vaguely remember the pattern wherein the maximum number of shaded squares possible increased by one each time the number of smaller squares increased.

It would be helpful if anyone could tell me the name of the problem or provide a link. Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen YES! This is very similar. Thanks.

Comment: Although the queens problem also forbids squares being in the same *vertical* line.